# Java Code to Run JIRA Jelly Script

Tags: java, jira, jelly

This is my Jelly Script to perform IssueLinking in Jira 4.2...This works fine when trying to ru directly in Jira4.2.

```
    <JiraJelly xmlns:jira="jelly:com.atlassian.jira.jelly.JiraTagLib">
    <jira:Login username="jiraloginname" password="jirapwd">
    <jira:LinkIssue key="issuekey1" linkKey="issuekey2" linkDesc="duplicates"/>
    </jira:Login>
    </JiraJelly>
```

This is my Java Code to call the JellyScript and Execute. But this throws some exception.

```
    JellyContext context = new JellyContext();
    Writer objWriter = new StringWriter();
    XMLWriter xmlWriter = new XMLWriter(objWriter);
    XMLOutput objOut = XMLOutput.createXMLOutput(objWriter);
    context.runScript("IssueLinking-Jelly.jelly", objOut);
```

When this code is executed, the following exceptions are caught.

```
org.apache.commons.jelly.JellyTagException: <jira:Login> com.atlassian.jira.jelly.tag.login.Login doesn't have any satisfiable constructors. Unsatisfiable dependencies: [[interface com.atlassian.jira.security.JiraAuthenticationContext]]
Caused by: org.picocontainer.defaults.UnsatisfiableDependenciesException: com.atlassian.jira.jelly.tag.login.Login doesn't have any satisfiable constructors. Unsatisfiable dependencies: [[interface com.atlassian.jira.security.JiraAuthenticationContext]]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The same issue linking functionality was fixed using Http Post method to the LinkExistingIssue page in JIRA.

Thanks.